# IllegalStateException LogicalConnectionManagedImpl is closed Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, h2

I'm using H2 Database with hibernate on JAVA and I'm getting a weird error.
I have created my abstract repository to manage the basic CRUD operation.

The exception I am getting is this:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl@d20d74a is closed
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.errorIfClosed(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:37)
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:135)
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:254)
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.rollback(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:116)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.rollback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:294)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.rollback(TransactionImpl.java:139)
at repositories.AbstractRepository.save(AbstractRepository.java:32)
at services.ResultService.saveResult(ResultService.java:76)
at services.API.WebRequestService.run(WebRequestService.java:124)
at services.API.ThreadService.run(ThreadService.java:67)
```

AbstractRepository save method:

```
public <T> T save(T t) {
    Transaction transaction = null;
    try (Session session = HibernateConfig.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        Serializable entityId = session.save(t);
        transaction.commit();

        T createdEntity = (T) session.get(t.getClass(), entityId);
        return createdEntity;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (transaction != null) {
            transaction.rollback();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I am a CS student and I am not very much familiar with Hibernate. I'm not getting this error on my computer, only on other computers with the JAR file builded.

P.S English isn't my main language so I am very sorry if you don't understand me clearly!

Answer (score 6):

After hours of debugging I found the error!
The error was that a column exceeded the length and the exception was coming from the catch block.
The catch block was trying to rollback something that its connection was already closed.
I hope this will be helpful to someone!

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error when trying to create an embedded relationship between two tables using Hibernate version 5.5.3. Yes the above answer was helpful for me to debug the error in a single go. Thanks to @William. It was same in my case too, the catch block was trying to rollback the transaction due to an exception occurred in the Embeddable class. The issue was that I did not have a default constructor inside Embeddable class.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Vikarm's answer and @William's answer pointed me to the right direction. You simply *need to create your composite ID in the constructor of the class that has the EmbeddedId*.

Here's how it looks like in code (full example is included for completeness purposes)

```
@Entity(name = "artwork_rating")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class ArtworkRating {
    @EmbeddedId
    private ArtworkRatingKey id; // This needs to be instantiated*

    private int score;

    private String content;

    // --------- Relations --------- //
    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("userId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("artworkId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "artwork_id")
    Artwork artwork;

    // --------- Constructors --------- //
    public ArtworkRating(int score, String content, User user, Artwork artwork) {
        this.id = new ArtworkRatingKey(user.getId(), artwork.getId()); // *as shown here
        this.score = score;
        this.content = content;
        this.user = user;
        this.artwork = artwork;
    }
}
```